# add Widgets from Backend without editing XML

Tags: magento

Is there any possibility in Magento to add a "widget" to the sidebar, using the backend only – without editing XML. I'd like to provide that function to a customer, who may add blocks/widgets to the sidebar similar like how it's possible using Wordpress.

Or did I have a false concept in mind of what widgets are in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

You can add widget to any static page/block. See this tutorial: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_widgets.htm